# ARMA regression

Tags: arma

I am studying stock price.

I first define that the ln(price) has an obvious unit root of 1 lag.

I was wondering if someone could explain me how to proceed to construct a correct ARMA model...?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `Box–Jenkins` methodology. Details are available [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins)

Comment: Thanks.... 
My doubt is about using the difference of the lnprice as dependent variable, 

> D(lnprice) c AR(1) ....

 or the normal lnprice and how do I know how many lag to use in the MA or AR.

This is the first difference correlogram I dont see any particular behavior at a first sight. Do I need to look at the lnprice?

http://postimage.org/image/89yunf647/

Comment: Yes you need to look at the lnprice not the difference. Please accept the answer if you are convinced.

Comment: so in this case you will run the arma model with lnprice as dependent variable?

Comment: You need to look into autocorrelation (ACF) and partial autocorrelation function (PACF)to determine whether it is AR(1) (or ARMA(1,0)) or MA(1) (ARMA(0,1)) or ARMA(1,1,) or some higher order times. If you are not sure,do  update your question with ACF and PACF, so that we can help you. What is your objective?

Comment: I need to define the arma, but I dont understand if I need to take the first difference or use the non-stationary lnprice as dependent variable. I thought you needed a stationary series for arma. I a little bit confuse on the step to follow.

Comment: A non-stationary is the special case of AR(1) with the coefficient on the first period lag of dependent variable (which is ln of stock price) equal to one. How did you test the unit root?

Comment: I used the ADF test. So which are the steps you would follow, knowing lnprice is non-stationar, to defined the ARMA(p,q) ....?

Comment: If you find stock price to be unit root, you can difference it to achieve stationarity. In, other words stock returns will be stationary or I(0). Next find the ACF and PACF of residuals from first difference model.If the residuals are white noise, you don't need to go further since it specifies that `ARMA(1,0)` or `ARIMA(0,1,0)`.Nice illustration using Eviews are available [here](http://staffweb.hkbu.edu.hk/billhung/econ3600/application/app05/app05.html).

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thank you. Can I ask you also what happen if I have that the correlogram present a significant (<>0) value only at lag 2 and with all the rest being insignificant (=0)?

Comment: Details [here](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm)

Comment: I know, but the lag on the I(1) has only a spike at lag 2 all the are are significantly equal to zero. I dont know if that indicate seasonality or what...? It doesent have any MA or AR shape...

Comment: I dont have enough reputation point to have a chat conversation, if you dont mind can we have a quick conversation

Comment: Sorry, I am not available for chat. I would recommend you to go for textbook by Walter [Enders](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Econometric-Times-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470505397). Could you please update the question with the results, so that it is more clear for me?

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/89yunf647/ ...... this is my first difference correlogram with significance only in lag-2. Q: Which arma would you apply..?? knowing that you have significance ONLY at lad-2.............. http://imageshack.us/a/img10/151/29549977.jpg <---- more clear

Comment: It appears to me that there are seasonalities in your data e.g.,  January effect, day-of-the week effect. Please do incorporate that and see whether it changes after that. If you are using `R`, you may find [this](http://scc.stat.ucla.edu/page_attachments/0000/0087/ts-R-1-09S.pdf) to be very useful.